# The Objective Reality: Honesty -> Truth -> Reality

Tags: empirical-apperception

### The Objective Reality

It is true the study of the subjective reality takes note of the personal experience and because we all have our seperate existence we all have our own mind and knowledge, but is there a way for reality to be objective while we maintain or subjective experience?

It can only be that a view of reality is formed from what is, therefore truth but truth can only be expressed or we may say interpreted by being honest. Without honesty we are not truthful with ourselves or others, honesty is complete honesty so we do not decieve any, so we must say to have truth in our knowledge we must have honesty, therefore we must be honest.

It is reasonable given study that is mainstream to say perception may be easily decided to a lesser extent in most stable individuals, but easy to show it is possible with slight of hand, or use of language that is not comprehended where the subject must be understood. But to be honest requires truthful comprehension. There can be no way to honestly comprehend reality without truth but does that make it objective.

If we remove bias we can see that we no longer favour our own knowledge to be complete or without a verifiable confirmation to be accurate. But we can being humble enough and without pride admit what we do not know, that is we do not know what we do not know, and the more I learn the more that there is to learn.

Professor. Damian A. James Williamson

Comment: Is your question "can we remain subjective?" Yes. Yes we can.

Comment: This isn't a question; it's a micro essay on your personal philosophy.

Comment: A good overview of the subject is at https://iep.utm.edu/objectiv/

Comment: Honesty only requires speaking to the best of one's knowledge, hence only the subjective reality is required to judge honesty.

Comment: Honesty cannot be subjective it must be objective to be observable and it remains true to say to the best of ones knowledge and is why most people are not capable of making systems of fact, where oneself must be able to be objective to establish the relationship with truth. They may say it is truth and not be accepted but for being honest it can be examined to see if it is lest if they are high with accomplishment of Oath.

Answer (score 3):

Objectivity is just reified intersubjectivity.

See

[According to the major theories of concepts, where do meanings come from?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/77261/according-to-the-major-theories-of-concepts-where-do-meanings-come-from/77284#77284)
and

[The Unreasonable Ineffectiveness of Mathematics in most sciences](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/92058/the-unreasonable-ineffectiveness-of-mathematics-in-most-sciences/92064#92064)

On understanding the language game which uses 'true': [Why is a measured true value “TRUE”?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/81655/why-is-a-measured-true-value-true/81664#81664)

Comment: That's one point of view. There are probably other points of view among various philosophers.

Comment: @Frank There are more views on objectivity than people. That's because the claim to objectivity is latently a normative claim that masquerades as free of bias, perspective, and influence. The logical positivists claim to fame is their attempts to reduce observation to the objective. They ran into the sticky wicket of [theory ladeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory-ladenness). Objectivity might be seen as that which is external to us, but the external as an object of intentionality has to deal with the subjectivity of representation. A really good work on how reality is determined...

Comment: is [Standards: Recipes for Reality](https://books.google.com/books?id=ILlNEAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=standards+busch&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiI_u6bvqf-AhW2j4kEHUX7D40Q6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=standards%20busch&f=false). "Standards are about the ways in which we order ourselves, other people, things, processes, numbers, and even language itself... as a category of experience, standards span the material and the ideal, the positive and the normative, the factual and the ethical, the sacred and the profane." Kant's TI might be seen as a proposed standard of experience.

Comment: Related I wrote this recently, https://twitter.com/CA_22562_AN/status/1688096807002488833?s=20

Comment: In a language words do not have their independent meaning per individual, rather we use concrete language to communicate and with that work to convey clear understanding. It could be some fail to persist that some people's honest is dishonest.