# Do computers use logic?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-logic, intentionality, philosophy-of-computer-science

I know we refer to computers as using logic, logic gates and the like, but is this just us ascribing human capacities to the machines? It sounds like a case of us giving more meaning to the machines than they deserve. I've read about things like derived intentionality and this seems to echo that.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146084/discussion-on-question-by-adkane-do-computers-use-logic); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Allow me to be precise about this. Logic (in the formal sense) is a system of manipulating symbols according to rules. Computers can manipulate symbols according to rules — that is more or less exactly what they are designed to do — so in that sense computers can use logic.

That being said, computers cannot (currently) *reason*. Reason entails more than the application of logic: e.g. valuation, goal setting, reflexive analysis, reversibility, error awareness, etc. A computer can manipulate symbols to get from A to B easily enough, but it cannot (currently) distinguish A or B from each other or any other proposition, cannot evaluate the importance or value of these proposition, cannot decide to do that manipulation on its own... You get the picture.

There are computers that are programmed to do mathematical proofs, and they occasionally create proofs that humans have been unable to solve. But they don't do it with intelligence; they do it with brute force. As a rule mathematicians dislike computer-generated proofs; not out of some prejudice, but because CG proofs are ugly and inelegant, the kind of disorderly mess we get when one simply hammers one's way through a problem. When (and if) computers are capable of choosing beautiful, elegant, and efficient proofs *over* ugly, inelegant, sprawling proofs, then we might start talking about computers using reason.

Comment: It's not merely aesthetics and beauty standards that make mathematicians dislike these proofs. The problem is rather that they don't "understand" the proof. Like with the more traditional logical proofs you've got to find a pattern that lets you untangle the mess, with computer generated proofs you essentially just get the confirmation that it is like that. There is no pattern that you've found, no idea or shorthand. It's axiomatic and if you want to explain it to someone else you'd have to run the program in front of them and verify the machine isn't corrupted. It doesn't feel like knowledge.

Comment: Minor nitpick: *"proofs that humans have been unable to solve"* doesn't really make sense. A proof is not something that can be solved. A problem could be solved by a proof. Or a theorem could be proved. But a proof cannot be solved.

Comment: Also, the core reason most mathematicians (that I know) don't like computer-generated proofs: Humans cannot make sense of them. We might be able to verify that they are correct, but they don't give us any insight into the nature of the problem or a proof. The provide the logic, but not the understanding.

Comment: "valuation, goal setting, reflexive analysis, reversibility, error awareness" - whether a computer can do any or all of these things depend very much on how you define each of them. A computer / AI can certainly e.g. have objective functions to evaluate things with or explore spaces and pick goals. And sure, humans program roughly how a computer goes about this, but one could similarly argue that a human's programming is its biology. It's oversimplifying the topic far too much to simply say computers can't do these things. And not all computer-assisted proof are brute force.

Comment: "That being said, computers cannot (currently) reason."
I'm not sure if this still holds true in 2023. There's AI's that can be given a picture, let's say a helium filled balloon on a string, and asked "what would happen if I cut the string?", after which the AI answers "The balloon flies away". I'd argue that this is some form of reasoning.
(Example taken from GPT-4)

Comment: @NotThatGuy: That's reductionistic. Even if human cognition is purely mechanical — which is far beyond what science can currently demonstrate, incidentally — There is clearly something different going on. Humans don't need to be explicitly programmed to do *anything*; they pop out of the womb and in short order set about trying to explore and understand their world. Computers come out of the factory and don't do anything except what they are told.

Comment: @Opifex: People fail to understand the significance of the inquiry/response distinction, which I think is attributable to 1940's anti-metaphisicalism (Russell, Skinner, Turing, etc...). We can train a computer (or a horse, a dog, or a rat, or even a student) to give an appropriate response to a given stimulus. For a computer that's a question of setting up proper programming, for the others it's a question of knowing what programming they already have and setting up proper punishments/rewards accordingly.

Comment: @TedWrigley "Humans don't need to be explicitly programmed to do anything" - uhh... humans are the result of billions of years of "programming" in the form of evolution. And even then, much of what we learnt is just the ability to learn: it takes quite a few years of near-constant learning before a baby is capable of doing much thinking (never mind how much knowledge is imparted by other humans - knowledge that was slowly gathered over many generations). By comparison, the programming of computers barely begin to scratch the surface of the "programming" of humans.

Comment: @Opifex: But what every teacher looks for is that moment when a student (or a dog, or maybe even a horse) seems to *ask the right questions* and seek out pertinent understanding independently. AIs are extremely sophisticated response machines, but I haven't seen any indication that (current) AIs question their world in any meaningful way. They just wait for a stimulus, and give a response. Maybe they will, which will be fascinating and scary (Because they will quickly develop some very *hard* questions about us humans), but...

Comment: @NotThatGuy: It's a good practice to wait 10 minutes or so before responding to a comment. That gives the commenter time to finish the thought, and it keeps conversations cool and level. I'll come back to your comment later, maybe

Comment: @TedWrigley I only responded after 11 minutes. You posted another comment to someone else in the mean time, and if I have to wait until 10 minutes after the last comment to anyone, that could be a lot of waiting. Also, if you're posting multiple comments, it's probably a good idea to write your entire response up front, and then copy these into multiple comments which you can post in short succession, rather than sending someone a notification, but then expecting them to wait for 10 minutes before responding (but of course it's different if you realise there's more to say after posting).

Comment: @NotThatGuy: You're right, I got confused.  Apologies. But I have to get to work so I'll come back to this a bit later

Comment: @TedWrigley Humans arguably "question their world" as a result of evolution, since it increases our chances of a survival. There's [an entire field of AI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) which is dedicated to reproducing this evolutionary process of iteratively improving AIs' performance in a task by killing off those bad at it. Also, much of AI development involves AIs "exploring": trying different things to find what works. AIs don't really ask questions because this arguably doesn't align well with how we program them, how we interact with them, what their purpose is, etc.

Comment: I upvoted because there's a lot of solid here. "computers cannot (currently) reason. Reason entails more than the application of logic: e.g. valuation, goal setting, reflexive analysis, reversibility, error awareness, etc." Computers are fully capable of valuation, goal setting, reflexive analysis, error awareness, etc. One form of error awareness is called exception monitor and handling, and any software of import uses this technique. Goal setting? There are classes of algorithms in AI that set and work towards goals...

Comment: Machine learning uses weighted connections to provide values as in [rule-based machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule-based_machine_learning) where artificial neural networks might be used to decide which rules to use in real-time by monitoring a data stream. Systems are also being developed to make better questions as in [prompt engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prompt_engineering). Food for thought.

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect, since computers, which by definition are universal machines, can reason by simulating, for example, the human brain. To reason is about software, not hardware. There are also logical research tools, like [automated theorem provers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving), which certainly show that computers can reason in limited ways already, by using today's commonly available software. Computers do not require any consciousness to do so.

Comment: Just as a general, undirected comment... I am disheartened by the number of intelligent, science-oriented people who assert speculation as fact in this topic area. I understand that there is a general ***belief*** among some that the human brain is a typical classical-dynamics type machine, and thus **in principle** the same as a standard binary, step-wise computational device (if differing in scale). But that is an untested hypothesis with little or no evidence to back it up. It's an interesting theory, but by no means a solid established fact, so please don't present it as such.

Comment: @TedWrigley I am disheartened by the number of "intelligent, science-oriented people who assert speculation as fact in this topic area" by stating things like "computers cannot (currently) reason", or that there is [a mind-brain separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind%E2%80%93body_dualism), even though we have no evidence of that (especially if one doesn't believe in [other] supernatural things). The computational brain hypothesis is fairly well-supported by psychology and neuroscience; it would be the default assumption until we proof a non-deterministic non-random form of matter.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: You can have whatever 'default assumption' you like; I'm not here to question deeply held beliefs. But we cannot rest a supposedly scientific conclusion on some tenet of belief. It is an **observable fact* that 'computers cannot (currently) reason' as humans do. Maybe 'in principle' they can, maybe not; That's for research to determine. But we cannot leap from 'in principle' to 'in fact'.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: And please note that you gave the game away a bit. I did not mention mind-body separation or any 'other' supernatural thing; that's a function of your belief system: something that you are fundamentally opposed to. If you pressed me to speculate, I'd suggest that human cognition is closer to quantum computing than digital processing — i.e., a system of superimposed states that only resolve when activated — and quantum computers are **not** Turing machines. But I do not use that speculation as the basis for ;'scientific 'conclusions because that is not fact.

Comment: If posed as a true or false proposition, then I would evaluate this statement as false: "Computers manipulate symbols according to rules." Why false? Symbols are abstract signs which acquire meaning in the context of human communication. Computers do not manipulate symbols. We build a physical device and we interpret states of the device as symbols. The Atmega328 processor architecture is represented in this diagram as a symbolic map https://www.watelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/Arduino-Architecture.jpg but the device does not manipulate symbols it has physical states and changes states.

Comment: @TedWrigley An alternative name for "default assumption" is "null hypothesis": you know, that thing that practically every scientific field recognises and makes extensive use of. If you're going to dismiss an entire extensively-reasoned epistemological framework as nothing more than "deeply held beliefs", then you clearly have no interest whatsoever in actually understanding the position of anyone else.

Comment: @TedWrigley Did you forget what you wrote in your own comment or something? You explicitly referred to the belief that "the human brain is a typical classical-dynamics type machine", and your entire answer is based on a rejection of this. That's also used to argue against a mind-brain separation, so for you to say you "did not mention" that separation is just laughable. And we have no indication that quantum mechanics falls outside of "non-deterministic non-random form of matter" - some believe it's random, some believe it's deterministic, so that's compatible with what I said

Comment: @SystemTheory: The on/off states of a single computer bit are associate with the numerical **symbols** 1/0 by design. In fact, early computers were little more than automatic calculators, meant to do symbolic manipulations of numbers that humans could feasibly do, but much quicker. I don't think a computer understands numerical symbols any more than a calculator does (or anymore than a hammer understands a nail) but human beings understand, designed these tools to serve symbolic purposes.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: 1. That is **not** what a null hypothesis is. If you need a primer in the philosophy of science, I have other posts that explain the null that I can point you to.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: 2. I explicitly suggested that ***many people*** hold the belief that "the human brain is a typical classical-dynamics type machine", which is true.  It was a subtle way of pointing out that you yourself are working from that belief system, in order to avoid giving you any offense. But subtlety does not seem to be your strong suit.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: 3. Again, I am not hear to criticize your beliefs, but I want you to stop acting as though your beliefs are unquestionably true (e.g., the heated, defensive tone you adopt here and in other threads, whenever I suggest your beliefs are not scientific canon). I get enough of that from religious fanatics, thankyouverymuch.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: TL/DR: Drop it. You have a full head of steam but no traction to speak of, so this is not going to get you anywhere.

Comment: @TedWrigley TL;DR: 1. Condescendingly pointing out how (you think) you know so much more than me. 2. "I was trying to not offend you, but also here's an insult". 3. Ignore the justifications I give for my beliefs, and then accuse me of unquestioningly holding to unjustified beliefs, lol. TL;DR: Some more insults and condescension. Also, I like how you managed to post 4 comments, yet you've addressed pretty much nothing I've written. Very constructive, thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: Glad you got my message.

Comment: I studied electrical engineering taking courses on analog systems, digital systems, computer architecture, and I programmed computers using assembly language and C. I can tell you that in a typical digital computer the symbolic values On (1) or Off (0) are set by voltage bands and a gap between the two bands to try to eliminate uncertainty of the gate state and analog noise.  Hardware engineers design the computer so that a programmer can map symbols onto the physical states which are the low voltage range and the high voltage range. If logic is manipulation of symbols computers don't do that.

Comment: @SystemTheory You may know plenty about computers, and so do I, but you should try learning a bit more about neuroscience, because you can make roughly the same argument there, to conclude that human brains "don't do [logic]". You've got yourself a [fallacy of composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_composition) there, in trying to conclude that the whole of the computer can't do something because parts of it can't do that. You're also [special pleading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_pleading) when it comes to the brain.

Comment: @NotThatGuy - Funny just before reading your comment I thought neurons only have physical states and electrochemical connections to other neurons. A light switch has two states that we call On or Off depending on the state of the light bulb. But neither the switch nor the light bulb are "manipulating symbols according to rules". Neither is a digital computer manipulating symbols according to rules. Neither is a neural network manipulating symbols according to rules. The neural network is also called a model free estimator that somehow makes us conscious of symbols, rules, and manipulations.

Comment: @SystemTheory I'm not really getting the point you're trying to make, but computers can emulate neural networks (that's what most of modern AI does), so that would throw a spanner into an argument that brains and computers have different capabilities based on their parts.

Comment: @NotThatGuy the "neural network" that AI research uses is an abstract mathematical construction. It is inspired by the basic surface-level principal of a brain, but is not attempting to actually emulate one.

Comment: @SystemTheory a digital computer at the hardware level is 100% manipulating symbols according to rules. Thus anything that runs on one (such as an artificial neural network) also works by manipulating symbols according to rules. Unless you have a non-standard definition of "symbol" and/or "rules"?

Comment: @OrangeDog: I think we need to make the distinction that *humans* design and use computers as tools to manipulate symbols according to rules. There's no real reason to believe that a computer (or even an AI at this point) grasps the concept of a symbol or a rule. To use an analogy I used before, a hammer is great at driving nails, but doesn't understand what a nail is, much less the purpose and use of a nail. Humans understand the hammers and nails on a symbolic level; hammers don't.

Comment: @TedWrigley "Understand" (and "symbolic level") is doing most of the heavy lifting in your comment there. We intuitively understand what it means to understand something, but I'm yet to see a concrete definition that necessarily excludes computers. If a hypothetical computer can behave in the exact same way a human does, using nothing more than capacitors and wires and such (we can argue to which degree computers can currently do this, but let's just leave it as hypothetical for now), you're going to have a hard time coming up with a definition that differentiates the two.

Comment: @TedWrigley a machine doesn't have to understand the concepts of what it's doing in order to do it. A toaster doesn't understand what bread it, yet it still toasts it. It has no concept of the number six, yet when you set it to six it still successfully burns it. Nor indeed does a human have to understand these concepts in order to operate it.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: Hypothetically speaking, a begonia can 'understand' in exactly the same way a human can, as can a rock, or a hammer, or an entire planet. If someone wants to believe that is true, nothing I say can stop them. But there's no *reason* to believe that's true, and there's no *reason* to believe it's true of a computer. Humans experience consciousness, which gives us a reason to believe we understand things (which maya turn out to false, granted). Why would you assume the same of computers?

Comment: @OrangeDog: Addition and subtraction can be done on an abacus. Same with a pile of stones. But it's humans who set the rules that make that work, and humans who understand and use the results.

Comment: @TedWrigley well yes, you keep giving examples of devices that don't manipulate something following a set of rules. Instead of an abacus, consider a calculator.

Comment: @TedWrigley You're the one who keeps asserting that the human mind is special, that something exists within the brain that we've never detected and have no evidence of. That there's more than what we have detected. And you also keep trying to shift the burden of proof to me to disprove this. That's much like asserting [there's a teapot floating in space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_teapot) because no-one has disproven it. Never mind that you ignore all evidence and justification against your claim (such as neuroscience and the incredible things computers/AI can do).

Comment: @TedWrigley I suspect you'll keep saying "computers can't reason" even when we have fully functioning androids walking among us, that can behave exactly like humans, because you seem to have an unfalsifiable claim there, that relies on an overly vague definition of "reason".

Comment: @OrangeDog: The point is that the system of symbols and rules are designed by humans, for human purposes.  The only difference between a hammer and a computer is that the computer is a more intricate and sophisticated tool. Without human intervention and direction neither would follow any rule system at all.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: When we have androids walking among us (if not before) then we will have evidence: something that goes beyond mere speculation and belief. I'm not averse to the idea that computers might develop human-like capacities in the future. I'm aware that they have not yet done so, and I'm not credulous enough to insist that something **is** merely because it **might be**.

Comment: @OrangeDog - A single switch, such as a light switch, has two distinct physical states, but the switch does not recognize the human meaning of the words "switch", "symbol", "rules", or "physical states". Then how can a switch change physical states to manipulate symbols according to rules? These are all human concepts. A bit in a digital state machine is a single switch that has two physical states. The human engineer or programmer must specify how the machine changes physical states in the context of performing computing tasks. Each neuron in a network is a switch with activation potentials.

Comment: @TedWrigley What are these "human-like capacities" you speak of, that you seem to think computers have never ever demonstrated before? 50, or even 20, years ago, if someone hypothesised about a computer being able to do what ChatGPT could do, many people would say that would be the evidence we need. All you're doing is pushing it beyond what we're currently capable of, with no justification beyond "we're not there yet". And I mean, yeah, sure, advancements we haven't made yet... haven't been made yet, but that's just a tautology.

Comment: @SystemTheory a single switch doesn't. Nor does a hammer. Nor does an abacus. However, a computer does.

Comment: @TedWrigley no, the difference between a hammer and a computer is that a computer manipulates symbols according to a set of rules and a hammer doesn't. Who designed the rules is irrelevant.

Comment: @OrangeDog - I think the word "symbol" is evoking a semantic argument. 1 - The computer is a state machine which transitions from one state to another when running code. 2 - States in the state machine have no inherent meaning. Source code maps meaning to the states and state transitions. 3 - When the state machine changes states it is not manipulating symbols it is implementing the machine code. 4 - We encode and decode the meaning of the states to implement rapid automated logic. 5. - Reverse engineering of machine code attempts to map symbolic meaning to machine states with no source code.

Comment: @SystemTheory How do you know that a brain is anything more than "a state machine which transitions from one state to another"? It's fairly trivial to argue that computers aren't like brains (or aren't capable of what brains are capable of) when you only consider computers, but you should consider both of the two things you're comparing.

Comment: @NotThatGuy - We recognize the meaning of symbols, rules, logic, states, and state transitions as concepts in our mind. But we do not know how neurons, operating as state machines, somehow generate the recognition of concepts in our mind. See article https://www.quantamagazine.org/artificial-neural-nets-finally-yield-clues-to-how-brains-learn-20210218/ wherein AI expert Geoffrey Hinton jokes about his knowledge of brains: “So, about a year ago, I came home to dinner, and I said, ‘I think I finally figured out how the brain works,’ and my 15-year-old daughter said, ‘Oh, Daddy, not again.’”

Comment: @SystemTheory So you're purely [arguing from ignorance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance) then? You can't say that computers aren't like brains based on the fact that you/we don't fully understand how brains work.

Comment: @OrangeDog: Don't be ridiculous. If I created a system in which driven nails represented 1s and popped up nails represented 0s, I could build a perfectly functional computer out of hammers. It would be slow, and loud, and dangerous to fingernails everywhere, but it would work. The distinction you're trying to make doesn't exist.

Comment: @TedWrigley no you couldn't. Hammers don't do anything by themselves. Hammers don't act according to rules (other than physics). In your system it is a human that's manipulating symbols according to rules, not the hammers. You could make a computer using hammers as a component, but that doesn't make a hammer a computer.

Comment: @SystemTheory the state of a computer is the current set of symbols. Moving from one state to another is manipulation of those symbols. At the physical level, a symbol is a pattern of voltage in particular circuits. They're manipulated by powering the circuitry around them in particular ways. As we all use von-Neumann architecture, the rules are also encoded as symbols, which may be the source of confusion.

Comment: Before trying to look at the philosophy of computing, one should probably first learn what computing mathematically is and how computers physically work.

Comment: @OrangeDog: See the wikipedia article on [mechanical computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_computer). They are a real thing, no different in principle than electronic computers, limited only by the implications of using moving physical parts. So yes, I ***could*** build a computer from hammers.

Comment: @OrangeDog: You seem to be stuck on the idea that electronic computers are manipulating symbols, when in fact all a computer does is sequentially change states (whether physical or electronic). These states are not symbols to the computer (at least not yet); they are only symbols to the people who design and use the computer

Comment: @TedWrigley I said you could. The computer you've built will then manipulate symbols (your up/down nails) according to rules. A single hammer by itself does not. A symbol is a symbol whether something knows it is or not.

Comment: @OrangeDog - Long ago I wrote code using the 8051 uC Assembler for my senior project in electrical engineering. I used a logic analyzer to debug the software. Recently I wrote code using AVR-GCC library tools and AVRDude to develop hardware and software projects for 8-bit AVR. If I write C code, then compile the program, the compiler creates binary machine code. AVRDude plus a programmer interface writes binary code to flash memory. If I analyze raw machine code, with no knowledge of how it was written, compiled, or the target uC it might be impossible to reverse engineer its symbolic meaning.

Comment: @NotThatGuy - Wikipedia - *In philosophy of mind, qualia (/ˈkwɑːliə/ or /ˈkweɪliə/; singular form: quale) are defined as instances of subjective, conscious experience.* 
Based on my conscious perceptions and concepts (qualia) developed in the context of self-other communication I know that the output of each neuron in a network is like a binary switch in a state machine. I do not know how distinctions (pattern recognition) or qualia emerge from building and training neural networks. I often wonder who is more ignorant or wicked (self-deceived) when humans disagree in the context of disputes!

Comment: @SystemTheory Do you think that a definition counts as evidence for the thing it's defining? Because either you think that, which is patently absurd, or you've missed every time I've mentioned how your conclusion is based on you not understanding how the brain works. And no, it's not a question of "who is more ignorant" - appealing to ignorance is a logical fallacy, which appears in your argument. Your argument would be fallacious regardless of how ignorant either of us are. It's unfortunate that you seem to have taken my rebuttal of your argument as a personal attack, and responded in kind.

Comment: @NotThatGuy - When I was young my older brother would often say, "Who died and made you the authority?" I think what I think independent of what you think; and you apparently do the same. I attribute that to the mystery of our brains. I am done having semantic arguments with you.

Comment: @SystemTheory You're the one who haven't defined any of your terms, who built an argument on a vague conceptualisation of how humans think, without being able to expand on or justify that. I mean, I guess you can think it's a "semantic argument" to point this out and to try to get you to make a more concrete argument. (You attribute us thinking differently to "the mystery of our brains"? Have you ever even written a line of code before? Computers can do fundamentally different things from one another based on their programming and input data - that's not particularly mysterious)

Comment: @NotThatGuy - Have you read my recent comment to OrangeDog above where I describe my experience writing Assembly and C code and my knowledge of how a digital computer (state machine) runs code? Do you know that my brain is somehow encoding meaning into these symbolic words in this sentence according to my subjective interpretation and that your brain is somehow decoding these symbols according to your interpretation? What level of definition is necessary and sufficient to describe the mysterious functions of neural networks or brains in your interpretation?

Comment: @SystemTheory I have read your earlier comments about you having written code, but the way you talk about brains makes it sound like you know nothing about coding, because much of the same ideas apply. From my perspective, you're taking some input, putting it through a black box, and generating some output. I can accept that you are, in some vague sense, "encoding meaning" and there are symbols involved, but if you're going to assert that this somehow excludes computers, then I can't accept that until you formally define what those terms mean and/or clearly justify why computers are excluded.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I am being flagged to move extended comments to chat. I say the same ideas do not apply to the physical substrate (computer running operation codes as an explicit state machine; neural network mapping inputs to outputs as a complex black box implicit state machine) and to the emergent properties of the artificial or organic mind. The cognitive properties of mind are called emergent because they are not explained by the reduction model incorporating the computer operation codes or the mathematical structures and algorithms used to build artificial neural networks. I hope you get it.

Comment: Upvoted, but I find your argument that computer "cannot reason" less than compelling, in part because you never define what "reason" mean. You also have to paragraphs that basically end with "If a computer could <do something>, then we could say it can reason, but currently they can't" and I find this distinction very arbitrary.

Comment: A computer could certainly be programmed to "evaluate the importance" of propositions and to "decide [what] manipulation [to do] on its own" or to "choose beautiful, elegant, and efficient proofs over ugly, inelegant, sprawling proofs" but I don't see why that would be a baseline for whether a computer is reasoning or not.

Comment: @Stef: Well, I'd define 'reason' (or at least delimit it, if not actually define it) as problem solving. Problem solving involves (A) recognizing that a problem exists; (B) imagining a counterfactual that would represent a solution; (C) constructing some path from A to B. As things stand, computers cannot do A or B, and can only do C through stochastic or brute force methods. And while we can feed a computer A and B, computers can;'t (currently) disagree: can't disagree that A is a problem or that B is a credible solution.

Comment: I'm a bit wary of this argument. I play the game of go and we now have computer programs that are stronger than humans. The main problem is "win the game", and the computer has been explicitly instructed to solve it, but solving this problem involves figuring out subproblems and solving them; we humans have conceptualised the solutions to these subproblems as "strategies" and "tactics", and the computer is able to identify these subproblems and solve them, even though it was never told that these subproblems existed and was never instructed to do anything more than win the game.

Comment: So it seems that the computer is able to do all of A, B and C in the context of the game of go. Yet it remains "only" a computer program, and is not conscious. Does it reason? I honestly cannot answer "yes" or "no" to this question; it certainly does *something*, but whether that counts as reasoning or not would require a precise definition of reason. I'm sure it's possible to come up with seemingly-reasonable definitions of reasoning for which the answer is yes and other equally seemingly-reasonable definitions for which the answer is no.

Comment: I've seen go players engage in long arguments about whether the go-playing computer program really had an "understanding" of the game. There are partisans of both sides: some say "yes, it understands the game much better than we do" and some say "no, it understands nothing and just applies calculations and gets a result". This debate feels empty to me: neither side is able to define what "understand the game" means. I have a bit of the same issue with the question of whether a computer can "reason" or not.By your ABC definition it seems a go-playing program can reason but that feels arbitrary.

Comment: @Stef: Hm. I don't think it's correct to suggest that your Go computer is figuring out subproblems and solving them, or even that its main problem is to 'Win the game'. The computer doesn't know that it's a game, or what it means to 'win'. internally, the program is running through a large number of technically legal moves looking for the ones that maximize some cleverly-written equations.  What you see as 'subproblems' (strategies) were never identified by the computer as a subproblem; that was simply how the same equations maximized for those conditions.

Comment: @Stef: A program can't be said to 'understand' the game in the sense that a human does. I mean, if we ask a human we s'he made a move, the human will say something about the game: the move attacked, or defended, or controlled a space, etc. If we could ask a computer the same question it would always say: "I tested lots and lots of moves using this function and this move had the highest score." But we can't ask the computer that, because it can't self-reflect and wouldn't process the question.

Comment: @Stef: It's worth noting that you can take the greatest Go computer in the world and try to play Chess with it, it won't be able to do a darn thing, much less win. Human Go masters can learn Chess, and maybe even start to win after a bit. They can switch problem sets in a way a computer currently cannot.

Answer (score 7):

You might like this answer: [Why is a measured true value “TRUE”?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/81655/why-is-a-measured-true-value-true/81664#81664)

Physicist Richard Feynman makes the case in this lecture that computers are essentially limited to sorting: [Hardware Software & Heurustics](https://youtu.be/EKWGGDXe5MA) (from 1986).

> logike, "branch of philosophy that treats of forms of thinking; the
> science of distinction of true from false reasoning," from Old French
> logique (13c.), from Latin (ars) logica "logic," from Greek (he)
> logike (techne) "(the) reasoning (art)," from fem. of logikos
> "pertaining to speaking or reasoning" (also "of or pertaining to
> speech"), from logos "reason, idea, word"
>
> From [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/logic#etymonline_v_12393)

Do computers use 'forms of thought'? You can split hairs semantically if you like. But I suggest they are able to make inferences by applying rules in exactly the same way humans do using formal logic.

The Chinese Room Argument applies, and the syntax semantics distinction. But I'd say 'form of thought' is syntax.

Comment: But computers make inferences without understanding so that looks to be something that distinguishes the way in which we infer. Hair splitting is where the fun is to be had in philosophy, and this split looks like the essence of many philosophy of mind problems.

Comment: @adkane: A lot of humans make inferences without understanding too. Mauro's point about an engine using the rules of thermodynamics without understanding them covers it I think. 'Thinking' is a slippery word, I'd look to family resemblances & modes of life to give it meaning, rather than try to find the word's essence & an exhaustive exacting definition that must diverge from use of the word anyway.

Comment: You are conflating analogy with description.

Comment: My brain cells make inferences without understanding anything.

Answer (score 5):

Computers use logic, but differently than people and other Great Apes.

Logicians make a distinction between formal logic and informal logic. Computers are fully capable of doing formal logic, but they struggle with informal logic because while formal logic is a syntactic system which is easily done by substituting symbols for other symbols, informal logic relies heavily on domain-specific semantics, including what some call the material logic of natural language. In the latter category, it's possible to build sophisticated software to replicate informal logic, but when done, it requires a lot of work from people to help codify extra rules, values, and language to emulate informal logic that human genes do with ease for human beings. [Expert systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system) are a special sort of AI that weighs through facts and draws inferences, and such systems ultimately rely on transistors and machine code. Of course, the human brain ultimately relies on neurons and epigenetic components of the nervous system, so human beings also have a physical basis.

Now, 50 years ago, there was a clear line between human reasoning and machine reasoning because the rules that were implemented had to ultimately be crafted by human programmers. However, today, the game has changed somewhat with [connectionist models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectionism) asserting some influence in systems. For instance, thanks to the ever-widening collection of [machine learning (ML) techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning), there are now [rule-based machine learning models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule-based_machine_learning):

> While rule-based machine learning is conceptually a type of rule-based system, it is distinct from traditional rule-based systems, which are often hand-crafted, and other rule-based decision makers. This is because rule-based machine learning applies some form of learning algorithm to automatically identify useful rules, rather than a human needing to apply prior domain knowledge to manually construct rules and curate a rule set.

What does this mean? It means machines are learning in the same way people do, that is through induction by repeated observations using information from the outside world. A computer vision system which learns faces does manifest [intentionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intentionality) in the same way a dog, chimp, or child manifests intentionality.

So, machines, particularly with systems such as cameras, sensors, and other robotic peripherals can learn from the environment, devise their own rules, and then use those rules to make decisions. That's the essence of how and why human's use logic. While we get our physical endowment from genes which have evolved, our machines are still largely designed, though there is also an increasing repertory of computational strategies to evolve design such as the use of [genetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) and ML strategies that mimic natural processes. While clearly the how's and why's are different from human beings and our use of logic, there is no disputing that sophisticated robotic systems that are designed to mimic human reasoning can and do use logic. "Using logic" is not a yes-no question, but one of degree, and there's little sign that computers and robots won't continue to use logic more and more like people as the systems become more sophisticated and research continues forward into understanding how the human brain and its neurons compute to provide human-level intelligence.

Comment: Nice, between all the bogus answers there is this one which is mostly correct. But "using logic" is indeed a yes-no-question when one is able to ask "Does X use logic?", which already declares it a boolean property, as by the question. Sure, there are different degrees and kinds of how logic can be used, but that was not asked about. A computer already uses logic because it applies it through logical gates. The question asked is that simple to answer. But the extension to higher reasoning is still a valuable addition. Though, computers being universal machines already implies this capability.

Comment: "Object-level vs meta-level" would be a more suitable and correct dichotomy than "formal vs informal". As it happens they correlate; but that's incidental.

Comment: @Rusi Interesting assertion. Are you saying that humans are capable of meta-logic in a way computers are not?

Comment: @xamid 'But "using logic" is indeed a yes-no-question". Oh, I agree 100%. It's a rhetorical strategy to use is instead of ought to insist on an ought, and an ought instead of an is when politely questioning the is.

Comment: @JD Yes. Reasoning = meta. Boolean (aka digital) logic = object. The 2 levels may *seem* alike but are 2 distinct levels

Answer (score 5):

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/logic#Noun):

> **Noun**
> **logic** (countable and uncountable, plural **logics**)
>
> 1. (uncountable) A method of human thought that involves thinking in a linear, step-by-step manner about how a problem can be solved. Logic is the basis of many principles including the scientific method.
> 2. (philosophy, logic) The study of the principles and criteria of valid inference and demonstration.
>
> **2001**, Mark Sainsbury, *Logical Forms - An Introduction to Philosophical Logic, Second Edition*, Blackwell Publishing, page 9:
>
> "An old tradition has it that there are two branches of logic: deductive logic and inductive logic. More recently, the differences between these disciplines have become so marked that most people nowadays use "logic" to mean deductive logic, reserving terms like "confirmation theory" for at least some of what used to be called inductive logic. I shall follow the more recent practice, and shall construe "philosophy of logic" as "philosophy of deductive logic".
>
> 3. (uncountable, mathematics) The mathematical study of relationships between rigorously defined concepts and of mathematical proof of statements.
> 4. (countable, mathematics) A formal or informal language together with a deductive system or a model-theoretic semantics.
> 5. (uncountable) Any system of thought, whether rigorous and productive or not, especially one associated with a particular person.
>
> "It's hard to work out his system of logic."
>
> 6. (uncountable) The part of a system (usually electronic) that performs the boolean logic operations, short for logic gates or logic circuit.
>
> "Fred is designing the logic for the new controller."

It is senses 1, 2, and 5 in which we use the word "logic" when discussing human behaviour. Specifically, deductive logic and inductive logic, which fall under sense 2, are the kinds that philosophers talk about.

It is senses 3 and 4 in which mathematicians use the word, also called "axiomatic logic" or employment of an "axiomatic system". One such system is that of Boolean algebra. These usages of the word to refer to the application of axioms to derive other true statements within that axiomatic framework naturally arose from the earlier sense in which "logic" refers to deductive reasoning.

It is senses 4 and 6 in which computer scientists use the word, and sense 6 is almost exclusively the sense in which computer hardware / embedded systems engineers and computer programmers use it. Specifically, the hardware of modern computers implements the logic of Boolean algebra. That is the job of so-called "logic gates".

See also: [Rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting) and [abstract rewriting systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_rewriting_system)

Comment: I like the citation of the taxonomy, but did you answer the question affirmatively or negatively? I can't tell.

Comment: An understanding of the different senses in which the word "logic" is used, and how the computational senses arose, should resolve OP's question. To directly answer it, though: "Yes, computers use logic, but not the kind you're thinking of."

Comment: So, which definitions do you claim computers cannot do? For instance, "senses 4 and 6 in which computer scientists use the word". It seems to me an AI researcher who is a computer scientist uses every sense of the word when discussing the application of logic to goal-oriented systems.

Comment: @JD I'm not making any such claims. I'm pointing out that OP is conflating the usage of "logic" in philosophy with its usage in mathematics and computer science. OP specifically asked about e.g. why logic gates are called *logic* gates. If you want to talk about whether we can create computers that can understand/learn abstract concepts and attempt to perform sound deductive reasoning in the philosophical sense, I think that deserves to be its own question, and indeed much research and debate has already been done and had in this area, and continues to be actively done and had.

Comment: The post said "logic gates and the like".  Which might be broader than NANDs as a basis for a ALU/CU/MMU. When taken with the tag applied by the OP, philosophy-of-mind and the invocation of the philosophical term "intentionality", I suspect the OP had a broader scope. As a software engineer, I think it's fair to say that the intersection of logic and computer science is far broader than Boolean logic. Turing Machines and formal languages associated with such automata can be used to build intuitionistic logics, eg. See [CHC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence).

Comment: +1 For a positive contribution.

Comment: @JD Of course the intersection is greater than *just* Boolean logic/algebra, but I believe that is entirely captured (if not only *almost* entirely captured) by sense 4. Constructive mathematics is indeed very cool/interesting, and I'm intimately familiar with the use of the CHC in that regard. It's still not deductive or inductive reasoning in the philosophical sense, which is what it seems to me OP is exclusively thinking of when they hear the word "logic".

Comment: Thanks for responding to a grilling! Welcome, and please continue to contribute. :D

Comment: You inspired me to ask a question. Take a stab at it. Thanks! https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/99310/is-rule-based-machine-learning-an-example-of-inductive-logic-in-the-philosophica

Answer (score 3):

Computers do not use logic.
They do however, use logic GATES.
Logic gates perform very small pieces of logic calculations like AND, OR and NOT, but this is not enough to say they use logic.

Computers follow instructions.  It is possible to program a computer to perform pretty advanced logic deductions, but most computers don't do this.
You *could* say that these computers use logic, but they are an exception, not the rule.

Comment: So an expert system doesn't count as using logic?

Comment: "but this is not enough to say they use logic" Why?
"Computers follow instructions" Yes, and they apply logic (thus use logic) while doing so. Actually, they are much more reliable than any human in using logic. Humans are just more creative.

Comment: I think the question hinges on the word 'use'. If something doesn't have agency, it can't be said to *use* anything. Similarly you can't say that computers "follow instructions".

Answer (score 3):

Difficult. I mean the question is basically where the "mind" or "soul" of the "entity" of a computer is located or whether it has or is any of that to begin with.

Like if you take your device and consider it a blackbox then somewhere inside of "it" something is happening that can be described by logical operations, so "it" "does" apply logical principles somewhere (by choice or accident).

The problem is that when you take away the blackbox and look at the inner workings then there is no agent and none of the components immediately presents itself as having the capability of being an autonomous agent. So there is nothing that could actively "use" something.

And if you think that electricity is some quantum black magic hocus pocus and that there's some hidden nonsense going on... Well you could build [mechanical computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_computer), [water based computers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxXaizglscw) and it hardly gets more transparent than this [plastic based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Nim) one running the game "nim".

So let's consider this case of [Dr. Nim](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/126419/amazing-dr-nim). Like where is the logic happening. Is it the user? The user sets things in motion with their input but they aren't doing any of the computation or apply logic. In fact the user just needs to be able to push a button and flip a switch no deep thought or logic required. Is it the current? In this case a marble? A MARBLE? While it moves the pieces it certainly isn't the marble acting logically. Is it the plastic thing itself? Kinda... sorta... kinda not.

Like it's something that moves and it moves according to logical rules, but actually it only moves by mechanical rules that aren't really "followed" by an agent, but just confirm to the laws of physics. If you'd turn it upside down or employ it in space it wouldn't work. That being said if you'd put a human into a hostile environment they also might seize to work.

To a degree the logical work is done by the programmer/engineer who constructed the gizmo, nevertheless when it's actually used they are no longer present. So for this creation, their "creator god" may as well be dead and it would not interfere with the scenario, so how important can they be? The logic is contained in the device itself not merely in the creator of that device.

Now for the sake of argument you could abstract from the device the algorithm that is at the heart of it and consider that to be the computer, in which case the user would be the one applying logic by following the logical steps while the program itself would not be using logic it would be an implementation of logic. However as we've already covered the user could as well be incapable of logic and is just starting the process while the device performs the heavy lifting. But is it "USING" logic? "IS" "IT", to begin with?

Now so far we could put the blame on the programmer and argue the computer is just a manifestation of an algorithm and thus is usage of logic but doesn't use logic.

However that doesn't quite cut it either anymore, because what about machine learning and self-programming computers? Like we can construct systems that improve their mechanism on the fly by being given a desired output, a capability to produce outputs, a set of parameters and a comparison function. Then an output is produced, it's compared to the desired output, if better suited, keep it if unsuited discard it and try again with different parameters, if close enough stop.

Now the programming part is no longer the part of the programmer. In fact it's possible that the program solves problems that were too complex for the programmer themselves. At the same time it's still the same non-thinking machine. The game might have become more complex but the concept remains the same. It's still following an algorithm, still only an application of logic in that maybe not even logic but probability. That being said when pushed to the extreme it could be chance find logical properties, like if you want it to present you with a decision tree, then it's perfectly possible that what you end up with is a logical diagram. So it's not just an implementation of logic but it creates implementations of logic.

Though given that it's still just passive material, does that count as "using" logic? And if it doesn't does our application of algorithms count as logic? Because in the end our "usage" mostly rest upon our biased perception of ourselves as agents rather than passive material, but if passive material is capable of such feats where is the line between the two?

Also even if there is a line and we are active and computers are certainly not, given that they produce logic and can be understood with logic, is it useful to think of them in terms of entities using logic? Like is our process of creating logical constructs similar enough for that analogy to be useful regardless of whether it holds.

And here it might come back to the programmer/engineer, because the computer way of thinking is largely modeled after our own way of thinking, though much of the programming currently happens at a level that is far removed from the actual processes so while it might have had been useful, we might move into a direction where it no longer isn't or we might coincidentally move in the same direction as our own way of thinking. But unfortunately as of right now we don't seem to know how our own mind and consciousness works to begin with so that a comparison to our most capable tools is always attempted but it's never clear as to whether it actually works like that.

Comment: Maybe Logic uses computers? Maybe Logic uses humans, as its ecosystem to expand and take over the universe? Many questions are asked backwards, in terms of humans, and should be asked as it using us. (asked by whom?)

Answer (score 3):

I think it is appropriate to quote George Boole here:

> No general method for the solution of questions in the theory of probabilities can be established which does not explicitly recognise, not only the special numerical bases of the science, but also those universal laws of thought which are the basis of all reasoning, and which, whatever they may be as to their essence, are at least mathematical as to their form.

The way I understand this is that he is proposing there are "universal laws of thought", of which the human mind as well as a computer are physical implementations.
This is meant with regard to their ability to work with logically provable statements, not creativity or the ability of abstraction, which classical computers are completely lacking.
Any problem a computer should solve has to be "presented and tailored to it" specifically by humans, but that does not take away from their ability to actually solve "logical problems" according to "laws of thought".

Comment: +1 Indeed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_thought Welcome!

Comment: IMO, you can distinguish between formal thinking, which uses a mathematical language and establishes truths by means of proofs built from axioms, using formal logic, and informal or *natural* thinking, which essentially produces fuzzy inferences, that are always interpretable in different ways and neither true nor false. Even expressing Newton's law of gravity isn't formal enough to get an absolute truth value.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I was referring to "creativity and abstraction" to distinguish between humans and computers. However the question was not "how different are humans and computers?" but "do computers use logic?" and the person I quoted invented the mathematical rules for logical calculations on which computers are based.

Answer (score 2):

Computers intensely use *formal logic*, which is built into them. Formal logic amounts to elementary arithmetic (AKA *boolean*) with the binary digits *0*, *1*, and the operators *not*, *and*, *or*.

Combining these operations in various ways, you reconstitute all arithmetic on integers and other numerical representations. All that computers can do is summarized as handling

- numbers (numerical applications),
- characters (text processing),
- programs (textual sequences of instructions to be executed automatically).

Programs do use a more advanced form of logic, closer to what we call first order logic, and programming is a task similar to theorem proving, which is still completely formal. But programming is anyway performed by humans, not by computers.

So, no, computers do not use logic in the sense of a cognitive activity: computers do not think, they have no mind, no consciousness, no nothing. But due to their speed and immense data storage capabilities, they achieve outstanding tasks that a human could never perform, just using zeroes and ones.

---

The question can be re-examined in the light of the famous Artificial Intelligence techniques, which aim at handling "knowledge" rather than "data". But so far, not a single droplet of intelligence has been obtained.

Comment: All a computer does is change the state of things from on to off or vice versa real quick.

Comment: Yes, in fact, the human way of conceptualizing things to make them more intuitively understandable is often why we have difficulty *really* understanding them, since we are approximating them at a surface level and we are confused when the metaphor reaches its limits and fails to predict further behavior. The fascinating thing about computers and related entities is that they do not “do” logic, they more *are* logic. Humans basically found a physical system that they felt could represent or stand in for a certain pattern they knew - so they use the system to embody the pattern.

Comment: @haxor789: I don't see how this comment is relevant to the discussion. What matters is to know whether the changes of state are the results of some thinking or just a huge but predictable/reproducible computation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What's the difference between thinking and deterministic computation?

Comment: @YvesDaoust What a vague response... Do you mean to say that the answer is obvious (in which case, what is it?), or that you don't know? Do you think there is such a difference? I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

Most answers are confused, and the problem is simple.

- *Logic* is the FORMAL set of rules that govern reason.
- *Reason* is the potential to think.

> I know we refer to computers as using logic, logic gates and the like, but is this just us ascribing human capacities to the machines?

No. Machines implement rules. We would be "ascribing human capacities to the machines" if we would say machines "think" or "reason". But they DO implement and apply rules, which imply they apply Logic.

> It sounds like a case of us giving more meaning to the machines than they deserve.

Badly expressed, but your point is somehow understandable. If machines implement Logic, and we want to communicate about it, we just do. That is, machines "deserve" it.

Comment: I'm not downvoting, but logic isn't necessarily formal. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informal_logic

Comment: @YvesDaoust Let's take the claim they can't. Do you have a philosophical source that provides a compelling argument, or is that your opinion (which is not to imply you are right or wrong, but merely asserting an original thesis)?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have no quarrel with that current AI is not sufficiently architecturally rich enough to create a functionalist equivalent of human-level informal logic, though I suspect it's more a matter of the inconceivability of the task given the realist constitution of the philosophy of mathematics that seems to dominate AI research paradigms. The physical symbol system hypothesis is hopelessly the wrong paradigm since it grounds semantics in the equivalence of other symbols as opposed to the systems of physical computation themselves which is the origin of most semantics obscured...

Comment: by the confusion surrounding the proper nature and role of dualism. And therefore the philosophical confusion in the Academy over the nature of physical computation is why AI programs which continually conceive of themselves as "technology projects" continue to fail to near broader goals of imbuing systems with dispositions that can be construed as intelligent more broadly. Too few computer scientists understand the failure of big symbol systems to understand that the goals must align more with using embodied systems to model informal logic more intelligently. That IS a philosophical problem

Comment: As for computing, as some who programs on a distributed architecture, it's only a matter of time before the resources scale up.

Answer (score 1):

@Ted Wrigley 's answer is excellent but it's omitting another hidden sub-question inside the original question: Neither the question nor the answer differentiate between what "*bare* computers" can do and what "*programmed* computers" can do.

A programmed computer can do anything. It can do all of the "cannots" that have been listed (that is, with enough programming efforts). When does it stop being "just logic" when a sufficient amount of logic gets used to create "reason"? You decide.

However, we might assume that the original question was asking only about what "bare" computers can do. It could be rephrased as "is computers' core design somewhat resembling logic?".

Under that assumption, everything Ted said is valid : *Yes*, they are built around logic principles, but *no*, "reason" is not part of the core design.

Answer (score 1):

**Digital Logic**

[https://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/digitallogic/](https://cs.lmu.edu/%7Eray/notes/digitallogic/)

> Believe it or not, we can model all computational processes (that we know of) by operations from, of all things, plain-old classical logic.

The reference shows how digital gates and other devices in digital computers are used to implement bivalent logic. These devices do not manipulate symbols according to rules because a symbol is an abstract sign recognized by a human intelligence (HI) or general artificial intelligence (GAI) if such entity ever emerges. The devices implement logic functions using physical system states and deterministic state transitions. We map symbols to the physical system states to program the logic gates or the computer which then performs rapid logic functions.

**Logical Neural Networks**

https://skirmilitor.medium.com/logical-neural-networks-31498d1aa9be

> Our first main idea is the use of constrained optimization during learning to guarantee logical behavior of all neurons in an LNN.

> Due to their 1-to-1 correspondence with systems of logical formulae, an LNN can also be viewed precisely as a collection of logical statements in real-valued logic (where truth values are not restricted to just 0 and 1 but can lie anywhere in between). In a separate, very fundamental work [11] we have shown that the larger class of logics to which LNN belongs is capable of sound and complete (i.e. correct and thorough) reasoning, to the same degree as has been shown for classical logic [ref: real-valued logic foundations blog].

> Thus, like the famous ‘wave-particle duality’ of physics, LNNs can simultaneously be seen entirely as neural nets and entirely as sets of logical statements, and thus able to leverage the capabilities of both the statistical AI and symbolic AI worlds.

> Before we can discuss LNNs further, it is necessary to develop an understanding of the computations their neurons perform. The output of a logical neuron is computed much the same as it is for any neuron by applying some nonlinear activation function f : ℝ → [0, 1] to a linear combination of its inputs w · x − θ for an input vector x, weight vector w, and activation threshold θ, as shown in Figure 2. Different from other neural nets, however, is that LNN’s neural parameters are constrained such that neurons behave according to their corresponding logical gates’ truth functions.

This reference refers to the effort to implement human logic and reasoning via so-called Logical Neural Networks. When humans interact with digital computers we can decode the explicit programming code or digital circuit logic functions. If LNNs begin to perform block functions of logic or reason in a limited domain then we have a black box that implements a function of logic or reason.

**Complexity**

There are problems that define system states and deterministic changes of state, but which are sensitive to both initial conditions and to unavoidable computation error associated with the use of rounding and truncation methods. In these cases if we run the automated computer algorithm, using the same initial conditions, to solve the problem for the path of evolution of the system, then we get different paths each time we run the computation. This gives rise to concepts of chaos and complexity theory in the domain of computational theory.

Answer (score 0):

Monkey-Man tears off an apple by own forces.

Man-Monkey takes a stick to tear off an apple by own forces.

Man create Logic.

Man took a stick to force a human to tear off an apple by his forces.

Man call this stick - Boomstick.

Man create a logic rules to force the robot-computer to took a stick to tear off an apple.

But robot computer is too expensive, then step back.

Man create a logic rules to manage a computer that force a human by logic rules, (that a human accepts) to took a stick to tear off an apple by his forces.

Does computer understand man's Logic?

No, but it use it's rules, same as human.

What ll Man do if logic rules will not works on humans??

Oh, Man still have Boomstick.

L=logic...

"a bit of the old ultra-violence" no one cancels.

Comment: "*The guns spell money's ultimate reason*" - poem by Stephen Spender

Comment: @ScottRowe paper and cyfral money as the cause are debt obligations of guns owner. Money or bullets - what is your free choice?

Comment: It seems that the one gives rise to the other.

Comment: @ScottRowe there are 2 causes for the money - first is "euphemismation": replacing a direct physical threat with a forced to loan; and second  - a trick: i give you seashells you give me gold. But anyway seashells are able to change back only for the bullets, not for the gold). So, the violence - two ways of money - and again the violence at the end

Comment: "*Why can't we all just get along?*"

Comment: @ScottRowe Nuclear War will make peace. I think God d thought similar when evented Great Flood, but he was bad scientist and didn't know about atomic decay and ect...

Comment: The cockroaches will be happy to take over the earth after we are gone.

Comment: @ScottRowe following genus should be better this we are, all have similar brown color and stylish mustache... some able to fly! Oh, they are already happy